# Jersey How to mask the password from the request

Tags: spring-boot, jersey

I am using spring boot with jersey implementation in that we are logging every request and response. Now it is logging everything but I need to mask the password in the request. in the configuration file, we are using this

```
register(new LoggingFeature(java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME),
                Level.INFO, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY, 10000));**
```

I cannot able to mask the specific field from the POST request. Please help

SAMPLE LOGS:

```
2 > POST http://localhost:9092/sampleapi/login
2 > accept: */*
2 > accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
2 > connection: keep-alive
2 > content-length: 69
2 > content-type: application/json
2 > host: localhost:9092
2 > postman-token: 24c72655-6f97-4e19-9503-6f013c859e5f
2 > user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
{
  "userId": "1111",
  "password": "TEST@1",
  "yob": "1997"
}
```

In this, I need to mask the password field alone